# convert datetime to local in Django

Tags: django, pytz

In my postgresql db my datetime are stored as the following format:

```
>>> p.publish
datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 6, 6, 19, 36, 269492, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

now I want to display times locally using

```
{% load tz %}
{{ post.publish|localtime }}
```

nothing happens.
Then I tried to do it in the shell:

```
from tzlocal import get_localzone
local_timezone = get_localzone()
pytz.utc.localize(p.publish,is_dst=None).astimezone(local_timezone)
```

which gives me the following error:

```
ValueError: Not naive datetime (tzinfo is already set)
```

so my question is why it cannot convert timedate when tzinfo is already set, and how to get around it. Is it not the whole point to store data in data base with a certain timezone(here UTC) and then display it in different time zones when required? am I missing something here?

Comment: What is `local_timezone`? A timezone object?

Comment: Perhaps [`localtime`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/timezones/#std:templatefilter-localtime) instead of `local` ?

Comment: thanks I adressed both comments, it is indeed localtime

Answer (score 0):

If the `tzinfo` is already set, you can replace it with the one you wanted to set.

For example:

```
import pytz
utc = pytz.UTC
_today_date.replace(tzinfo=utc)
```

Here, `_todate_date` is `datetime` object.